# matplotlib change xticks scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following questions. How can I change 1e-5 to 10^-6 on the xaxis in the diagram bellow? Is there a way to set the scale consistently to 10^-6 when I zoom into the diagram?
[image]

Comment: you can try the margins method to zoom in and out

Comment: You will need to use [scilimit](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html), probably (-5,-7)